# Installed Ubuntu, now I get "fatal err. not os detected

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu. Now I get:

```
"fatal err. not os detected.
```

I cant boot from dvd either

What can I do?

Comment: Is preboot right? You can't boot the DVD, nor USB, it's not a problem of grub.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what you did I would guess you have broken your boot loader.

Look at this question and try the second method [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

boot from live cd and run these commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```